# Setup Google Analytics's to track image or page views on another site

Tags: google-analytics

Scenario

- Site (A) which I control and have
  Google Analytics setup on.
- Site (B) which is controlled by a 3rd
  party but we are allowed to customise html including images/javascript (e.g. something like a directory page)

Is it possible to use Google Analytics to track visitor usage on site (B) alongside site (A) ? - e.g. we can already see how many people visited from B but we can't see how many viewed so can't work out CTR.

- Is this possible with Google Analytics?
- If not, is this possible with any other hosted analytics package or is it back to images and log file analysis?

Answer (score 2):

If you can insert the tracking link, you SHOULD be able to do this.  I just depends on the specifics of how Site B allows you to integrate.